# I want to remove all elements of a list if a substring matches

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list as shown and want to remove all other elements of that list but only if 'None' or 'Not Chosen' and have two of these Words:

```
List = ['None, Pink, Green', 'Blue, Not Chosen', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green, Red']
```

The List I Want:

```
List = ['None, None', 'Not Chosen, Not Chosen', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green, Red']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s difficult to know what you mean, but this code will produce the required output:

```
List = ['None, Pink, Green', 'Blue, Not Chosen', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green, Red']

def make_replace(item):
    if ‘None’ in item:
        return ‘None, None’
    if ‘Not Chosen’ in item:
        return ‘Not Chosen, Not Chosen‘
    return item

List = [make_replace(item) for item in List]
```